# How to check if attribute value exists in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes

How to check if attribute value exists in magento2...

Comment: are you talking about attribute option value ?

Comment: Yes, i want to check attribute option exist of not..

Comment: Based on option label?

Comment: Exactly!! I want this

Comment: try $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute');

and also this for multiselect

$this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'attribute',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {       
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;    
    }
```

Now,

```
$attr = $this->_productFactory->create()->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
if($attr){
    $label = 'test';
    $optionId = '';
    $getId = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($label);
    if(!empty($getId)){
        $optionId = $getId;
    }
    return $optionId;      
}
```

Comment: please let me know if yoy have still issue

Comment: hi @Rakesh, How to check if option id exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute');
```

and  this for multiselect

```
$this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'attribute',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```